# How to reshape Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reshape

I have a small table which looks like:

[[image: Table 1]]

I want to convert this table into another form:

[[image: Table 2]]

I have written the following code:

```
usmacrodata = pd.read_csv('f:/Predict2/usstat.csv')
usstat=usmacrodata.stack()
usstat.to_frame().reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't work. What are my mistakes? Please, help me, I am a beginner... :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality that you're looking for is pandas.DataFrame.transpose()

If you want to switch rows and columns this can be done by calling transpose on the pandas dataframe, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
datadict = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=datadict)
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
df_transposed = df.transpose()
print(df_transposed)
      0  1
col1  1  2
col2  3  4
```

See this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html